# Extract not matching rows from one column of two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

df1:

```
   name     data
0   C       'nnnn'
1   B       Nan
2   A       'yyyy'
3   D       'zzzz'
4   E       Nan
```

df2:

```
   name     data
0   A       'qqqq'
1   B       'vvvv'
2   C       'uuuu'
3   D       Nan
4   G       'pppp'
5   F       'mmmm'
```

I want the columns where name rows match and those that don't.
Matching columns were easily found. pd.merge(df1, df2, on='name')

And referred to the link page.
[Pandas Merging 101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101)

When I applied the code,

```
(df1.merge(df2, on='name', how='outer', indicator=True)
     .query('_merge != "both"')
     .drop('_merge', 1))
```

got this result...

```
   name    data_x   data_y
0   C      'nnnn'     Nan
1   A      'yyyy'     Nan
2   E      Nan        Nan
3   G      Nan       'pppp'
4   F      Nan       'mmmm'
```

**result I want. (Exclude matching columns in row name)**

```
   name     data_x    data_y
0   E       Nan        Nan
1   G       Nan        'pppp'
2   F       Nan        'mmmm'
```

'name' in df1 and df2 mostly match each other but are mixed.
I want to find columns that belong only to df1 or df2.
searched for a long time, but I don't know how.
I am a beginner in python and not good at English  too, sorry.
help me please.

Comment: Check your output , I use the code and get the expected output

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @BENY, your code actually works just fine:

```py
>>> (df1.merge(df2, on='name', how='outer', indicator=True)
     .query('_merge != "both"')
     .drop('_merge', 1))
  name data_x data_y
4    E    ...    NaN
5    G    NaN    ...
6    F    NaN    ...
```

That said, you can also use set differences, especially if you don't actually want to have two columns and remove the NaNs, but instead just want to pinpoint which `name` values are absent on one side or the other:

```py
miss = set(df1['name']).symmetric_difference(df2['name'])
```

Then:

```py
>>> df1.loc[df1['name'].isin(miss)]
  name data
4    E  ...

>>> df2.loc[df2['name'].isin(miss)]
  name data
4    G  ...
5    F  ...
```